# Prepaid phone number provider in Sydney / Brisbane airports

Tags: airports, australia, cellphones

Does anyone know if there are any mobile prepaid phone provider store at Sydney / Brisbane airport? And if so, do they stay opened 24 hours?

I'll have a flight link at SYD 17:45 and after that I'll arrive at BNE at 21:30, and getting myself a mobile number is my number one priority.

Comment: See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39807/what-are-the-options-for-a-prepaid-sim-card-in-australia/39900#39900

Comment: I don't remember the details, hence a comment.  A couple of years ago I arrived in Sydney and git a prepaid Lyca Mobile sim card from a newsagent type store.  They had a selection of about 5 or 6 different operators, including Vodafone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [Sydney Airport](http://www.sydneyairport.com.au) web site, under FIND, go to the [Telecommunications](http://www.sydneyairport.com.au/find/service-categories/service-listing.aspx?cat=%7B613DC877-71E1-4C1A-9B3F-A610DA97F416%7D) page. From there, you can see there are Optus and Vodafone locations. Under "More information", they all show that they are open until 22:00 every day.

Both Optus and Vodafone are available in the [Brisbane airport](http://www.bne.com.au/store/welcome) also (Under "Currency Exchange / Other Services").